# Table Overflow Fixed Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with a fixed initial column.  Is it possible to have a horizontal scrollbar that is always visible when the table overflows vertically?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmvkgcj6/2/)

I tried adding a scrollbar outside of the table div, but it doesn't workin in IE10.

```
Namespace.prototype.linkTableScrolling = function() {
var table = $('table');

var bs = $(".bottomScroll", table), ts = $('.content', table);

ts.scroll(function() {
    bs.scrollLeft(ts.scrollLeft());
});
bs.scroll(function() {
    ts.scrollLeft(bs.scrollLeft());
});

$(".immun-o2-schedule-bottom-scroll > div", table).width($("table", table).width());
};
```

Comment: Why you don't use css?

Comment: "have a *horizontal* scrollbar that is always visible when the table overflows *vertically*?" is that a typo or do you have a reason for this? Might help us understand better what you want.

Comment: In the fiddle above, as the number of rows exceeds the available vertical space, you actually have to scroll down to see the horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css.

```
.content {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

It ensures that the horizontal scroll bar is always visible.